# HQL does not accept update SQL with join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I need to run this SQL in my java application to a MySQL database:

```
update group_table 
join
  (
        select tab1.letter, tab1.id_group_table from 
        (
          select  letter,
          id_group_table, 
          count(letter) as occurrences
          from letter
          group by id_group_table, letter 
          order by occurrences desc
        ) tab1
        group by tab1.id_group_table having max(tab1.occurrences)    

  ) tab2 on group_table.id_group_table = tab2.id_group_table

set champion = tab2.letter
where group_table.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4);
```

It works if I try it in the database. Now here's what I'm trying to do using hibernate:

```
String hqlUpdate = "update group_table join (select tab1.letter, tab1.id_group_table from (select  letter,id_group_table, count(letter) as occurrences from letter group by id_group_table, letter order by occurrences desc) tab1 group by tab1.id_group_table having max(tab1.occurrences)) tab2 on group_table.id_group_table = tab2.id_group_table set champion = tab2.letter where group_table.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4);";
getSession().createQuery( hqlUpdate ).executeUpdate();
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
Ago 04, 2014 12:16:18 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:38: expecting "set", found 'JOIN'
line 1:38: expecting "set", found 'JOIN'
    at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.setClause(HqlBaseParser.java:414)
```

I need to run this exact query...
**How can I do that with hibernate**?

THanks!!

Comment: use native SQLQuery,not HQL with Session.createSQLQuery()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
String hqlUpdate = "update group_table join (select tab1.letter, tab1.id_group_table from (select  letter,id_group_table, count(letter) as occurrences from letter group by id_group_table, letter order by occurrences desc) tab1 group by tab1.id_group_table having max(tab1.occurrences)) tab2 on group_table.id_group_table = tab2.id_group_table set champion = tab2.letter where group_table.id_whatever in (1,2,3,4);";     
getSession().createSQLQuery( hqlUpdate ).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need exact query then don't use HQL, use [native query support](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) instead.